# Finding solutions of a 2-variable biquadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Find all integral solutions of $$y^2+y=x^4+x^3+x^2+x$$ Factoring both sides we get $$y(y+1)=(x^2+x)(x^2+1)$$ Let $Y=y+1/2$ and $X=x^2+\frac {x+1}2$. Therefore $$(Y+1/2)(Y-1/2)=(X+\frac{x-1}2)(X-\frac {x-1}2)\\=>Y^2-1/4=X^2-\frac {x^2-2x+1}4\\=>4Y^2-1=4X^2-(x^2-2x+1)$$ What should I do after this?

Comment: You mean integer solutions?

Comment: yes..i think it is obvious from the question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that $(x,y)$ is an integer solution, we have:

$$(2y+1)^2 = 4x^4+4x^3+4x^2+4x+1. \tag{1}$$
The RHS of $(1)$ is greater than $(2x^2+x)^2$ unless $x=-1$. In such a case $y\in\{-1,0\}$ gives two solutions. The RHS of $(1)$ is less than $(2x^2+x+1)^2$ for any $x$ outside $[0,2]$, so we can have integer solutions only if $x\in\{-1,0,1,2\}$. Now computing them is easy:
$$\{(-1,-1),(-1,0),(0,-1),(0,0),(2,-6),(2,5)\}.\tag{2}$$

Comment: $(2,5)$, not $(2,11)$.

Comment: Could you please solve my question "finding value of 1-variable in a 3-variable $2^{nd}$ degree equation"...

Comment: @AbhishekBakshi: for such a question, you already got a precious hint: Vieta jumping is the way. An upvote would be nice, anyway.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: The thing is, i tried to use that technique but since I am not familiar with it(i heard it for the first time anyway), I was not able to get the answer, so some help would be appreciated..